# Angular 2 how does loading of component styles work?

Tags: css, angular, components

In Angular (Angular 2) if I have multiple instances of the same component on the page, is the CSS loaded more than once?

Does this make the page size bigger hence the load time slower.

Is it more efficient to move the CSS into a global css file instead?

I'm using style URL in the component.